# biblatex: indexing work title under author and title

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I try to achieve something a bit complicated with `biblatex's` indexing options. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@book{morus,
Address = {Louvain},
Author = {Morus, Thomas},
Publisher = {Nomos},
Title = {Utopia},
Year = {2014}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:title}{%
     \iffieldundef{title}
       {\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index}    
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\namepartprefix}
          {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{index:name:title}{\index}
          {\namepartfamily}
          {\namepartgiven}
          {\namepartprefix}
          {\namepartsuffix}}}

\newbibmacro*{cbx:index-name-title}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames[name:title]{labelname}}
    {}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{cbx:index-name-title}
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\def\xindyopt{-C utf8 -M texindy}
\makeindex[program=truexindy,columns=1,options=\xindyopt]

\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
\citetitle{morus}
\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I first define a `\citetitle` command which puts the title of the book into the index. I then make use of the `{index:name:title}` macro which is already defined in `biblatex.def`. This does not simply put the title into the index, but sorts it as a subitem under the name of the author. Like this:

[image]

This works fine, but I want more: I also want an index item under the title of the book which then refers to its author. So in this case I also want the following entry:

*Utopia, see* Morus, Thomas

I tried to do this by inserting something like `\index{\thefield{title}|see{\printnames{author}}}` into the `\citetitle` command, but this does not work since the author name is not resolved at the needed moment.

**EDIT:** The current solution is to use either of these two constructions:

```
\index{\citetitle{\thefield{entrykey}}%
    |see{\citename{\thefield{entrykey}}[]{author}}}

\index{\emph{\thefield{indextitle}}%
        |see{\citename{\thefield{entrykey}}[]{author}}}
```

None of them is perfect yet. `citetitle` uses the correct formatting, but does not take `indextitle` into consideration. `\thefield{indextitle}` uses the correct field, but here I have to hardcode the formatting.

Comment: I think I came up with something myself. The following addition to the `cbx:index-name-title` macro does the trick: `\index{\emph{\thefield{title}}|see{\citename{\thefield{entrykey}}[]{author}}}`. The only drawback is that I have to hardcode the formatting of `title`. Or is there a general formatting command, which allows me to use the format defined for `title`?

Comment: `\printtext[title]` should format its argument with the appropriate `title` format of the current entry.

Comment: @moewe: This does not work. I get an "Undefined control sequence". This command is not resolved when it is put into the .idx file. In general, higher level `biblatex` commands do not seem to work here.

Comment: Ahh, though luck then. Do you think higher or lower-level commands are worse (intuitively, I'd have thought higher-level would be better)? What about `\citetitle{\thefield{entrykey}}`?

Comment: It's not that I have any preference here. `\citetitle` does indeed work here. There is just one catch – which I did not mention in my initial question – it should actually be the field `indextitle` and not `title`. And there is no command for this AFAICS.

Comment: Of course there is `\citefield{\thefield{entrykey}}[title]{indextitle}` where the optional argument is to give the format.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that you could do this. Very nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just realized that this creates a new problem: With `\citefield`, the command is written to the .ind file and only resolved at he very end, when the PDF is created. At least for `xindy?, this means, that the entry is not sorted under `indextitle` but under the citekey which is the only data available at this point. With `\thefield{}`, the content of the field is already resolved and therefore the index entry is sorted correctly.

Comment: What about the `@` for sorting: `\index{\thefield{indextitle}@\citefield{\thefield{entrykey}}[title]{indextitle}|see{\citename{\thefield{entry‌​key}}[]{author}}}`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It looks like the `\indexentry{} just gets too complex at this point.  I end up with entries like `\indexentry{Looking Forward@\citefield {Keyes.K:1969a}‌​[title]{indextitle} |see{\citename {Keyes.K:1969a}[]{author}}}{3}`which doe not resolve properly anymore. In the final PDF, the output looks like this: `[title]indextitle , siehe Skinner, B. F.` (but it sorted properly).

Comment: After playing around with this, it seems like`\citefield` does not work at this point for some reason.